# Редактирование большого файла

Tags: php, текст

Есть много файлов, в каждом ровно 200 строк, необходимо в каждом из них приписать в начале значение, цифра на конце которого будет меняться вместе с переходом на следующую строку. Как и где это можно реализовать? Есть возможность написать что то на php, только как?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Понятно только что вы хотите что-то приписать в начало. А что именно - не понятно. Уточните

Comment: @Manitikyl
в начало надо приписать имя переменной, для каждой строки своё, тоесть
$var1 = 'val1';
$var2 = 'val2';
и так 200 раз, val уже имеются, а вот $var приписывать в начало в ручную как то не особо

Comment: А как файлы называются? тоже по порядку от 1 до 200?

Comment: файлы я могу и в переменную засовывать, ничего страшного

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите в каждом файле в каждой строке дописать val1-200, в зависимости от номера строки, правильно понимаю?

Comment: им и так грозит обработка до нужного вида, просто как массово приписывать новое значение для каждой новой строки - вот тут я не догнал

Comment: да, правильно понимаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = 'abc.txt';

$array = file($file);
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k) { $v = "val$k $v"; });
// Если начинать надо с 1, то так:
// array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k) { $k++; $v = "val$k $v"; });
file_put_contents($file, implode('', $array));
```

Цикл думаю осилите :)